# Posting blog from external PHP in EasyBlog

Tags: joomla2.5, easyblog

I am trying to post a blog entry in EasyBlog component of Joomla 2.5. I managed this so far:

```
$blogTable = EasyBlogHelper::getTable( 'Blog' );
$blogTable->bind($data);
$blogTable->store();
```

Strangely I get this error when the code is calling `store()`

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method JRegistryFormat::getInstance() 
in site_root/libraries/joomla/registry/registry.php on line 277
```

Any idea how I can get this work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that calling `setlocale` prior to calling `store()` caused the problem. I don't know the root cause of the error but I am guessing it might have something to do with easyblog loading its config file.